# How to change image size with this JS code

Tags: javascript

Basically, I have a page where 2 random images get generated using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 var imlocation = "images/";
 var currentdate = 0;
 var image_number = 0;
 function ImageArray (n) {
   this.length = n;
   for (var i =1; i <= n; i++) {
     this[i] = ' '
   }
 }
 image = new ImageArray(3)
 image[0] = 'image1.gif'
 image[1] = 'image2.gif'
 image[2] = 'image3.gif'
 var rand = 60/image.length
 function randomimage() {
currentdate = new Date()
image_number = currentdate.getSeconds()
image_number = Math.floor(image_number/rand)
return(image[image_number])
 }
 document.write("<img src='" + imlocation + randomimage()+ "'>");
//-->
</script>
```

and then repeated again using different variables so both images are random. I need the sizes of both images to be the same. CSS doesn't seem to be doing the trick using .img and specifying the height and width. Is there another way I could do it?

Comment: Why don't you like to use css height and width?

Comment: have you given `class='img'` to your images?? if not then just use `img{..}` and not `.img{...}` in your css. A `.` in css matters a lot

Comment: Use `width` and `height` element properties or CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CSS doesn't seem to be doing the trick using **.img** and specifying the height and width

With CSS, you indicate named classes with a starting period (i.e. `.mycssclass { }`), whereas with named elements you just specify the element name (i.e. `img { }`). So this could be why your styles aren't being applied.

Comment: Firmed. It appears my common sense was lacking more than my generic CSS skills. Thanks for this.